# Using integers produced by other classed

Tags: java

I am generating a random integer `ranNumber` in my class `Randomiser` but I would like to manipulate this number in a second class, `NumberManipulation`.

I have made an attempt, which I have /* */'d out of the code.  As it stands running NumberManipulation will run Randomiser - but that is all.

Any ideas?

Class 1:

```
import java.util.Random;

public class Randomiser {
    public Randomiser() {
        Random randomGenerator = new Random();
        int randomInt = randomGenerator.nextInt(3);           
        int ranNumber = 10 + randomInt;
        System.out.println(ranNumber);
    }

    public void main(String[] args) {
        new Randomiser();   
    }
}
```

Class 2:

```
public class NumberManipulation {
    public NumberManipulation(){
        new Randomiser();
        /*
        int a1 = 20;    
        int building = ranNumber + a1;
        System.out.println(building);
        */
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new NumberManipulation();
    }
}
```

Comment: You seriously need to visit and read [the official Java tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/). There are lots of misconceptions here.

Comment: Could you please recommend some specific trails?

Comment: Start in the Getting started section, then keep going through the tutorial.

Comment: It looks like you were studying C-language before. The biggest difference is that Java is strictly object-oriented. If you look after what this means, then you'll better understand the posted solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to help you.. ("not exactly" the right way to do it.....)

```
import java.util.Random;

public class Randomiser {
    //attribut
    public int ranNumber;    

    //constructeur, called everytime you instanciate an object of this class
    public Randomiser() {
        Random randomGenerator = new Random();
        int randomInt = randomGenerator.nextInt(3);           
        this.ranNumber = 10 + randomInt;
        System.out.println("ranNumber : "+this.ranNumber);
    }

}
```

and

```
public class Test {
    //Method
    public static void numberManipulation(){
        // instanciate an object of the class Randomiser
        Randomiser randomiserInstance = new Randomiser();
        int a1 = 20;    
        // get the attribute of the instance and add 20
        int building = randomiserInstance.ranNumber + a1;
        System.out.println("building : "+ building);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        numberManipulation();
    }
}
```

**But as Luiggi Mendoza said, you'll have to read the guide**

(class/object), (attributes/getters/setters), (singleton, bit more complicated)